# I can't access the data stored in my sessionDates array in my DateList function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

I can't access the data stored in my sessionDates array in my DateList function

this is the code from my index.js including the api call

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
const availableDates = [];
const available = [];
const sessionDates = [];

function getDates(e){
  getDate(apiUrl);
}

const getDate = async (apiUrl)=>{
  const res = await fetch(apiUrl)
  try {
    const data = await res.json();
    availableDates.push(data);
    availableDates.map((datee) => {
      datee.map((session) => {
        sessionDates.push(session.date.slice(0, 10));
      });
    });
    return sessionDates;
  }  catch(error) {
    console.log("error", error);
  }
}
window.addEventListener('load', getDates);

function DateList(){
  return <section>{sessionDates[0]}</section>;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While you are setting `sessionDates` based on the api call, there is nothing in your code that prompts `DateList` to re-render when `sessionDates` changes. As such, it will only display the initial value of `sessionDates`, for which `sessionDates[0]` is undefined.

Instead, I recommend that you use [the `useEffect` hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) to trigger your api call and implement `sessionDates` using [`useState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate).